# Combine case classes without enumerating arguments

Tags: scala

Suppose I have some case classes that I want to combine into a larger class. I can do that using overloaded constructors like this:

```
case class A(a: Int)
case class B(b: Double)
case class C(a: Int, b: Double) {
  def this(a: A, b: B) = this(a.a, b.b)
}

val a = A(1)
val b = B(1.0)
val c: C = C(a, b)
```

The problem with this is that it involves writing out every single argument in the `this(a.a, b.b)` line, and if your case classes take a large number of arguments, this is tedious and inelegant. What I want to do is somehow "splat" the case classes into the larger class by writing something like `this(a _:*, b _:*)` or something similar so that I don't have to write out all the arguments. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Why do people always want to make complicated things just to save writing a bit of boilerplate?

Comment: Because we are lazy.

Comment: No, if you were lazy, you would just make the boilerplate. Anyways, off topic. -  This may be doable with **Shapeless** but the code will end up being extremely complex to understand an change, hope someone may help _(I can't)_ -  just remember, that the code is read more times than it is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it for fixed classes `A`, `B` and `C`, that's pretty simple with the [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library. Just convert `A` and `B` to `HList`s, append those lists, and convert the result back to `C`:

```
import shapeless.Generic
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._
import shapeless.syntax.std.product._

object C {
  def apply(a: A, b: B): C = 
    Generic[C].from(a.toHList ++ b.toHList)
}
```

You can do it in a more generic way. For example, you can use not only fixed classes `A` and `B`, but any 2 case classes or tuples that can be appended to match the shape of `C` exactly. The code for that basically asks `shapeless` to provide implicitly all the necessary operations (conversions from and to the case classes to `HList`s and appending the `HList`s) and then executes those operations:

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.Prepend
import shapeless.{Generic, HList}

object C {
  def apply[A, B, HA <: HList, HB <: HList, HC <: HList](a: A, b: B)(implicit
    genA: Generic.Aux[A, HA],
    genB: Generic.Aux[B, HB],
    genC: Generic.Aux[C, HC],
    prepend: Prepend.Aux[HA, HB, HC],
  ): C = genC.from(prepend(genA.to(a), genB.to(b)))
}
```

Note that there are runtime costs to the `shapeless` approach in both cases, which may be undesirable for something so simple as appending two classes.

Answer (score 0):

Using Scala 3:

```
import scala.deriving.Mirror

case class A(a: Int)
case class B(b: Double)
case class C(a: Int, b: Double)

val a = A(1)
val b = B(1.0)

val c: C = summon[Mirror.Of[C]].fromProduct(
  Tuple.fromProductTyped(a) ++ Tuple.fromProductTyped(b)
)
```